# Assigning grep output to a variable

Tags: environment-variables, grep

In a terminal I type:

```bash
grep '<td><a href="http://www.blabla.cc' file.txt
```

works fine.
But if I type:

```bash
var= `grep '<td><a href="http://www.blabla.cc' file.txt`
```

I am unable to extract the variable,
the result is:

```bash
<td><a: can not find command
```

I tried a backslash before the space "href"
but

```bash
echo $var
```

shows an empty line.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It is the same command as given below, but for some reason askubuntu.com added a ";"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using spaces before the backtick. Additionally, use `$( .. )` instead of backticks and quote it:

```bash
var="$(grep '<td><a href="http://www.blabla.cc' file.txt)"
```